# Simulating the exponential function with pertubation

Tags: matlab, simulation, numerical-methods

for some simulations, I need to make use of an approximation of the exponential function. Now, the problem that I have is that:

```
function s=expone(N,k)
s=0
for j=1:k
    s=s+(exp(-N+j*log(N)-log(factorial(j))));
end
end
```

is a pretty stable, in the sense that it is almost 1 for k large enough. However, as soon as N is bigger than 200, it quickly drops to zero. How can I improve that, I need large N. I cannot really change the mathematical why of writing this, since I have an additional pertubation, my final code will look something lie:

```
function s=expone(N,k)
s=0
for j=1:k
    s=s+(exp(-N+j*log(N)-log(factorial(j))))*pertubation(N,k);
end
end
```

THe pertubation is between 0 and 1, so that's no problem, but the prefactor seems not to work for N>200. Can anyone help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the purpose of the approximation, instead of using the exponential function itself? What do you mean by "it is almost 1 for k large enough"? An exponential is not supposed to equal 1, is it? What do you mean by "quickly drops to zero": when further increasing `N` or increasing `k`? What do you expect from you function?

Comment: Should it be pertubation(N,j) instead of pertubation(N,k) ?

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that our!

Comment: You should use a logfactorial function insteal of log(factorial). But does it make sense to go to such large N ? The terms of the Taylor expansion are very quickly decaying.

Answer (score 1):

The function log(x) - x has positive and negative part
[Graphic in Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28x%29-x)

while x - log(x!)  is negative for x>= 0 
[Graphic in Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-log%28factorial%28x%29%29)

So the problem arise when (N - log(N) ) is much greater than (j - log(j) ). So the solution is to choose a j much bigger than N . Exp(negative) tends to zero

for example expone(20,1)  = 7.1907e-05  but expone(20,20) =  0.5591 and expone (20,50) = 1.000

As conclusion, if you want to work with N big, j should be bigger, and as an extra tip you may want to change you function to avoid for loops:

```
function s = expone(N,k)
j = 1:k;
s = sum ((exp(-N+j*log(N)-log(factorial(j)))));
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Just two issues: When I use your code, and I want to plot it (I mean a vector, varying N) I just get a constant plot, it doesn't seem to process the vector. Secondly, you would suggest I start summing when j is very large, so j>>N?

Comment: I also find that using the stirling formula helps, because factorial breaks down for large numbers...

Comment: Yes, I tried with Stirling's formula and it is even more stable. on the other hand the code can be used by vector either by using arrayfun or for loop